# Sagemaker: continual fit error after one failure to fit

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I am implementing some Sagemaker SKLearn examples:
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_iris
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest

I can successfully run them and all is happy. However, if I deliberately introduce a bug into the training script .py file, for example by adding
`import boto3`
which fails because boto3 is not installed on the training docker image, then for the iris example I get the error

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sagemaker-scikit-learn-2019-09-30-05-13-53-184: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -m train --max_leaf_nodes 30"
```

and a similar error for the random_forest example. That is all fine.

What I do not understand is that when I remove the offending line of code from the script, returning to precisely the code which had already ran successfully, I get the same error.

I have tried stopping and re-starting the notebook instance but the error remains.

Comment: can you go in the Sagemaker Training job console and scroll at the bottom of the training job detail page to check the logs and post the error here? logs will contain a more detailed error.

Comment: Looking at the log in cloudwatch I find:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/opt/ml/code/train.py", line 25, in <module>
raw_data = [pd.read_csv(file, header=None, engine="python") for file in input_files]
File "/opt/ml/code/train.py", line 25, in <listcomp>
raw_data = [pd.read_csv(file, header=None, engine="python") for file in input_files]

...

the training script is train.py

Comment: and do you re-save the script after fixing it? the SDK is creating a copy of your local file to s3 for SageMaker to read it so make sure that the file you send to the SDK is clean and persisted locally

Comment: right, this is the sourcedir.tar.gz. 
So I am doing this from a sagemaker notebook instance. I have a notebook which I run the sdk commands and I make a textfile with the script and save it as train.py. but yes, Im saving my changes.

Comment: so just to be clear. The pattern is that it works perfectly the first time, then if I add a breaking change it fails (which it should obv) then I remove the change and it fails.

Comment: And did you check in the sourcedir.tar.gz that is sent to S3 that the file uploaded there indeed contains your modification?

Comment: yes I have checked that the train.py in the sourcedir.tar.gaz is exactly the same as in the sagemaker notebook instance